# Excel VBA WinHttpRequest saved Credentials

Tags: excel, vba, credentials, winhttprequest, credentialscache

I wrote the following code to get the innerHTML text of a website:

```vb
Public Function GetInnerHtmlBody(ByVal Url As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim ResponseDocument As New HTMLDocument

    Dim MyRequest As New WinHttpRequest
    With MyRequest
        .SetTimeouts 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000
        .SetProxy HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, "<PROXY_SERVER_IP>:<PORT>", "*.domain.com"

        .Open "GET", Url, False

        '// Authentication for the proxy server
        '.SetCredentials "<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>", CREDENTIALS_FOR_PROXY

        .Send

        '// Debug
        MsgBox .ResponseText, vbInformation, .StatusText & " - " & .Status

        ResponseDocument.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
    End With

    Set GetInnerHtmlBody = ResponseDocument
End Function
```

As you can see the line `.SetCredentials` is commented out. This line was only needed once to authenticate with the proxy server but now it seems like the login credentials were saved, because even if i exlude the row the code successfully retrieves the html code of the given website.

I restartet my computer and cleared the whole IE cache but the code still works.

1. My question is now where are the `Credentials` saved? Coockie?
2. Is there a way that the HttpRequest uses the IE proxy settings? -> No need of asking for Username and Password.

Comment: If you don't set a proxy the system default is used IIRC. Are the credentials in the windows store? `cmdkey /list`

Comment: `cmdkey /list` is empty.

I tryed to use the system default proxy before i entered the credentials but it doesn't work.
The proxy settings are "normally" coming from a *.pac file which is configured to use in the IE -> Settings -> Connection -> LAN -> Script.

Comment: (trying to think outside the box) Is it possible that the session is saved server-side?

Comment: @SO i don't know exatly how i should confim that - but i tryed checking the GET request using  fiddler: `Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive` as well as `User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0`.

Comment: Have you checked the Credentials store for the calling user?